# NopCommerce: How to generate DLL file by updating the project build output path of custom plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.2

I want to make a Test plugin for **nopcommerce** and as the [documentation](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/plugins/how-to-write-plugin-3.90.html) says, I have to create a folder at `/plugins` directory and the name should goes like this:

`Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Test`

Now I need to update the project build output path. But I don't know where should I do that !

So if you know how can I do that and properly generate the DLL, please let me know, I would really appreciate that (my career depends on this)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the output path in the .csproj file of the just created project.
I've attached an image as where to click in visual studio. The example is identical to your situation, only difference is that the desired plugin's name is 'Payments.CheckMoneyOrder' instead of 'Widgets.Test'.

Next, edit the output path as demonstrated in the xml below. In your case, this would mean replacing the 'Payments.CheckMoneyOrder' by 'Wigets.Test'.
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju2KM.png)

````xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Copyright>Copyright © Nop Solutions, Ltd</Copyright>
    <Company>Nop Solutions, Ltd</Company>
    <Authors>Nop Solutions, Ltd</Authors>
    <PackageLicenseUrl></PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://www.nopcommerce.com/</PackageProjectUrl>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce</RepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>Git</RepositoryType>
  <!--Edit your output path here! -->  
<OutputPath>..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.CheckMoneyOrder</OutputPath>
    <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="logo.jpg" />
    <None Remove="plugin.json" />
    <None Remove="Views\Configure.cshtml" />
    <None Remove="Views\PaymentInfo.cshtml" />
    <None Remove="Views\_ViewImports.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="logo.jpg">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="plugin.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Views\Configure.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Views\PaymentInfo.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Views\_ViewImports.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\Nop.Web.Framework.csproj" />
    <ClearPluginAssemblies Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- This target execute after "Build" target -->
  <Target Name="NopTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <!-- Delete unnecessary libraries from plugins path -->
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ClearPluginAssemblies)" Properties="PluginPath=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutDir)" Targets="NopClear" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```
````